# 'TypeError : element is null'. when invoke the getElementById in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make my web page with pug.
When I clicked the 'mod user' button, the browser should show one of user names.
My index.js is follows.

```
block content
    div(class='s1tablediv')
        div(class='userListContainer')
            div(class='userInfo' id='userInfo')
                p(id='userID')

        script.
            function fuserInfo(arg) {
                $('.userInfo').text('');
                var userIdElem = document.getElementById('userID');
                userIdElem.innerHTML = arg.innerHTML;
            }
```

But, when I clicked the button, I got 'TypeError: userIdElem is null'.
If change the code like this,

```
            div(class='userInfo' id='userInfo')
            p(id='userID')  // unindent one level.
```

It works well.
Please tell me why.

Comment: Did you try waiting for the document to load completely? `Document.onload`?

Comment: Try to Check out Order of Script it should be After Your Html in Your Source, & Even Not Satisfied Do What Nikhil Wagh Says

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Script Start to Evaluate

`$('.userInfo').text('');` Removes Paragraph With Id UserID
Then You Try To Select The ID with document.getElementById('userId')

Because It's No More In DOM it returns Null